# Metatrader 4 Expert advisor with custom indicator problem

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, metatrader5

So it basically has 3 lines, and i want for long trades that  closed bar price has crossed middle line up, but not upper line. i Cannot get it work in my if statement.

At the moment i do get middle line cross up, but it also shows buy signal if candle crosses upper line which is not good. Please help...

[image: Indicator is similar to this]

my EA code:

```
// the input variables of the EA
input ENUM_TIMEFRAMES    TimeFrame       = PERIOD_CURRENT;
input int                AMAPeriod       = 10;
input ENUM_APPLIED_PRICE AMAPrice        = PRICE_CLOSE;
input int                Nfast           = 2;
input int                Nslow           = 30;
input double             GCoeff          = 2;
input int                PriceFilter     = 5;
input maTypes            PriceFilterMode = ma_smoo;
input bool               Interpolate     = true;


//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
  {
//---
   
//---
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert deinitialization function                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
  {
//---

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//---

   double band_middle = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter, PriceFilterMode,Interpolate, 0,0 );
   double band_1 = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode,Interpolate, 1,0 );
   double band_2 = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode,Interpolate, 2,0 );
   double band_3 = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode, Interpolate, 3,0 );
   double band_up = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode, Interpolate, 4,0 );
   double band_down = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode, Interpolate, 5,0 );
   
   
   //strategy
   double band_middle_curr = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter, PriceFilterMode,Interpolate, 0,0 );
   double band_middle_prev = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter, PriceFilterMode,Interpolate, 0,1 );
   double band_up_prev = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode, Interpolate, 4,1 );
   double band_up_curr = iCustom(_Symbol,_Period,"kaufman_ama_averages_filtered_ATR bands",TimeFrame, AMAPeriod, AMAPrice,Nfast, Nslow, GCoeff, PriceFilter,PriceFilterMode, Interpolate, 4,0 );
   Comment(band_up_prev);
   
   
   if(Close[0] >  band_middle_curr && Close[0] < band_up_curr)
      {
      
         Print("open a buy order");
      
      }
   
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You are using some custom indicator there. No one here knows what's inside that indicator's code and what buffer contains what data. Most likely, you aren't getting the upper line value band_up_curr or middle line value for band_middle_curr (e.g., they are swapped or something).

Answer (score 0):

Use Close[1]. Close[0] is the current bar which is not finished yet.